# T follows exponential law, what is E(T^q)?

Tags: probability, expected-value, exponential-distribution

"T is a random variable that follows an exponential law. Show that (for q a whole number)

$$ 
 E[T^q] = (q-1)!E[S](µ_T)^{q-1} $$

With $ µ = E[T] $ and $ S ∼ Γ (1/(µ_T),q) $ "

Anyway I know that it simplifies to $ E[T^q] = q!(µ_T)^q $... My question is simply how could this be? Shouldn't the answer simply be $ E[T^q] = (E[T])^q = (µ_T)^q $? Or have I severely misunderstood something?

Comment: Go back to basic definitions: $E[g(T)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)f_T(t)\;dt $ where $f_T$ is the PDF of $T$.

Comment: It is absolutely not true that $E(T^k)=E(T)^k$.

Comment: But isn't it true that if X and Y are independant variables, E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)? If so, I fail to understand why the same property can't be used here.

Comment: The random variables $T$ and $T$ are not independent.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what is meant by $ E[T^q] $. I thought what we meant by that, is the expectancy of the number that we will obtain if we look at the value of T q times, and then multiply those values together. If we did that, wouldn't the different values of T we would get be independant?

Comment: Yeah, I completely misinterpreted $E[T^q]$. It's the expected value if we take T once and raise it to q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $T$ is exponentially distributed with mean $\mu$, then $T$ has density $\frac1\mu e^{-\frac t\mu}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t)$. Hence
$$
\mathbb E[T] = \int_0^\infty \frac t\mu e^{-\frac t\mu}\ \mathsf dt = te^{-\frac t\mu}|_0^\infty -\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac t\mu}\ \mathsf dt = \frac1\mu e^{-\frac t\mu}|_\infty^0 = \frac1\mu.
$$
Assume now that $\mathbb E[T^q] = q!\mu^q$ for some positive integer $q$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[T^{q+1}] &= \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{q+1}}\mu e^{-\frac t\mu}\ \mathsf dt\\ &= (q+1)t^{q+1}e^{-\frac t\mu}|_0^\infty - \mu(q+1)\int_0^\infty \frac{t^q}\mu e^{-\frac t\mu}\ \mathsf dt\\ &= \mu(q+1)\mathbb E[T^q]\\ &= \mu(q+1)q!\mu^q\\ &= (q+1)!\mu^{q+1},
\end{align}
so by induction we conclude that $\mathbb E[T^q] = q!\mu^q$ for all positive integers $q$.